# Which of the IAM permissions and firewall rules take precedence

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-vpc

The GCP docs say that all resources within the same VPC network can communicate by default. But if the firewall rules were to be manually changed to restrict access to some resource, and at the same time an IAM policy would allow access to the same resource, which of the two would take precedence?

Comment: IAM grants access via permissions. Firewalls block access from/to IP addresses and/or TCP/UDP ports. The Internet knows nothing of IAM Roles/Permissions and is not affected by them. IAM affects identities and not network connections provided you are not using a service that grants access to identities such as IAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewall rules always win. Indeed, authenticated or not, authorized or not, if the traffic is blocked,  you can't do anything.

*Grant a user the authorization (with IAM) to access by SSH to a VM, if you don't open the port 22, it never works.*

Be careful to a common confusion with the firewall rules: You can select a service account as source of your firewall rule. Here, there is not in relation with the IAM authorization, but only with the identity (the service account) of the VM.

*A request sent by a VM can have the correct identity to be allowed by the firewall rules but it can be rejected by the target service because of insufficient permission*